# Twig: Add username and password to `absolute_url()`

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Is it possible to generate an absolute URL in Twig, containing username and password?:

```
http://foo:bar@example.com/
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggested this as a feature for `absolute_url()` but it got rejected: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/30281

So here's the self-made solution I came up with: Create the following [Custom Twig Filter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html):

```
public function addUsername(string $url, string $username, string $password)
{
    $delimiter = '://';
    $parts = explode($delimiter, $url);
    return $parts[0].$delimiter.$username.':'.$password.'@'.$parts[1];
}
```

And use it like this:

```
{{ absolute_url(path('route-name'))|addUsername('foo', 'bar') }}
```